# Exception Class declared but not thrown

Tags: java, exception, unreachable-code, defensive-programming

Here test is not throwing an Exception object , yet i had handled it . Since Exception is an checked exception shouldn't it throw a compiler error of unreachable code in the catch block

```
class Ece extends Exception {}
public class Excep {
    public static void test()  { }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            test();
        } catch (Exception E) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Exception` is the parent of **both** checked and unchecked exceptions. So you are not prevented from catching `Exception` in code that doesn't declare checked exceptions (clearly because runtime exceptions may be raised)

Comment: Because `test()` might throw any unchecked exception also, which would be caught by the `catch` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `Exception` has `RuntimeException` as subclass. `RuntimeException` and its subclasses do not need to be declared in methd signature.

In this case you are catching all possible subclasses of `Exception`, including all that subclasses that do not need signature declaration. If your `test` method throws for example `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` you will be able to catch and handle it, yet `test` signature will not be affected.

Further reading [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/checked-vs-unchecked-exceptions-in-java/)